# How to find time complexity of recursive function?

Tags: python, time-complexity, binary-tree

**Problem Statement**: Given a binary tree and a number ‘sum’, find all paths from root-to-leaf such that the sum of all the node values of each path equals ‘sum’.

**How do I calculate the time complexity of this algorithm?**

**What is its recurrence relation?**

```
   def func(currNode, sum, currPath, allPaths):
       if not currNode:
           return
       currPath.append(currNode.val)
       
       if currNode.val == sum and not currNode.left and not currNode.right:
           allPaths.append(currPath)
       else:
           func(currNode.left, sum-currNode.val, currPath, allPaths)
           func(currNode.right, sum-currNode.val, currPath, allPaths)
       currPath.pop()
```

Comment: Btw, better to avoid using `sum` or name of any other built-in function as a name of argument/variable.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I've written ```sum``` here only. I already knew that it's a good practice to avoid using built-in function names. But, thanks for reminding me of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's assume the height of the tree is **H**. Also, assume that recursion creates a full binary tree so, the **number of nodes per level is going to be 2^0, 2^1, 2^2,..... 2^(H-1).**

```
 def func(currNode, sum, currPath, allPaths):
       if not currNode:
           return
       currPath.append(currNode.val) # ----------------> O(1)
       
       if currNode.val == sum and not currNode.left and not currNode.right:
           allPaths.append(currPath) # -----------------> O(H)
       else:
           func(currNode.left, sum-currNode.val, currPath, allPaths) # --> T(H-1)
           func(currNode.right, sum-currNode.val, currPath, allPaths) # --> T(H-1)
       currPath.pop() # ---------------------------------> O(1)
```

Note that, `currPath` is a list containing the nodes of all the paths from root to leaf. So, appending that list to the list `allPaths` is going to cost us O(H). **Remember, the height of the tree is 'H'.**

So, **Final Recurrence Relation is**: `T(H) = O(H) + 2T(H-1)` ----- (1)

`T(0) = 1` ------- **base case**

Let's solve the recurrence relation:
**substitute H with H-1 in equation (1) and call it equation (2)**:

`T(H-1) = (H-1) + 2T(H-2)`  -------------------- (2)

On solving (1) and (2), we get: `T(H) = H + 2(H-1) + (2^2)T(H-2)` --- (3)

On solving few more times, we get this pattern:

`T(H) = H*(2^0 + 2^1 +...+ 2^(k-1)) + (2^k)T(H-k) - [(2^1)*1 + (2^2)*2 +....+(2^(k-1))*(k-1)]`     ------------- (4)

`T(H) = H*(2^k  - 1) + 2^k - k*(2^(k-1)) - 2*k`   --------------- (5)

Now, when H-k = 0, we get T(H-k) = 1 (base case). **So, k = H**.

**On, substituting k = H in (5) we get**,
`T(H) = O(H*(2^H))`  -------------- (6)

Equation (6) is the final complexity of the above algorithm.
Now, let total nodes in the recursion tree be N, then N = sum of total nodes on each level. i.e., `N = 2^H - 1` or `H = logN`.

So, the time complexity can be re-written as: `O(NlogN)`

Answer (score 0):

This is O(N).  There's no looping, and you'll visit each node exactly once.

Comment: I have the correct time complexity of this algorithm, but I don't have proof of it. Its correct time complexity is **O(NlogN)**

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that.  I'll have to digest that answer.